# identify image belong to product before submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

My product form have the AJAX image upload facility. So user can upload image before form is submitted. My problem how can i identify the images belong to this product before the product form is submitted. I developed my own mechanism

I have 2 tables

```
Products(id,ProductName,UND)

Image(id,UND,PATH)
```

Product form

```
    <form action='save.php' method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='product_name' value=''>
    <input type='hidden' name='UND' value="<?php random_string('50')?>">
    <input type='button' id='upload_image' value='Upload'>
    <input type='submit' id='' value='Post Product'>
    </form>
```

And for the unique number i have this function

```
<?php
    function random_string($length) {
        $key = '';
        $keys = array_merge(range(0, 9), range('a', 'z'));
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $key .= $keys[array_rand($keys)];
        }
        $key= time().$key;
        return $key;
    }
?>
```

I'm saving images with same UND to identify the image belong to that product.

Questions

1) This method works but i think it is lot of hassle to archive such simple task. There should be simple way to do that.

2) How can i delete those images if form is not submitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel the mechanism is correct, you could run a cron job which check if a product exist with the unique codes. if not present delete the images. BTW why would you want to upload image before product is created

Setting up cron: (depends upon OS)
you will have to write a php/mysql script which would have array of unique codes from the product table and check if images are present with with unique code, if not found delete the image from database and disk too .

Now you will have to setup at what interval you want to run this script. refer the link for more  http://www.tecmint.com/11-cron-scheduling-task-examples-in-linux/

Comment: Due to user can select the product profile picture. This is just part of form.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple and straight forward solution is to transparently submit form at early (using AJAX) to obtain your product id and mark it as "draft" so it wont be shown anywhere. Also save creation date. And when user submit form you just update it and "publish".

So you can upload images right to that product_id.

And you need to setup cron task that will run periodically and delete unpublished products older than certain time according to creation time.

Comment: Can you show me structure of corn job, according to above tables.

Comment: if you will adopt my sollution you cron task will run simple php file with one single SQL query like `"DELETE FROM products where created_time < ".time()-24*60*60` it depends of how often you want to run your cron (24*60*60 = 86400 sec = 24 hours) if you will save timestamp into DB, or you can save `datetime` so you need to calculate datetime `date('Y-m-d h:i:s', timestamp()-24*60*60)`. Also you can run sh script instead of PHP with such DB query if you like.